Media playback controller should not send for video playing in webView
I am developing an ios app inside it I have a webview which is playing some video. Apple is sending a mediaPlayback control notification and this notification can control the video (forward, backward, pause, resume etc...). I dont want this media controller to be appear on lock screen. Is there any way by which i can tell apple to not send this notification.
enter image description here
I have try setting audioSession category to playback but its not working, it is sending notification still but that notification become null as webview disappear.
